# Solve system of equations with integration over regions

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, regions

I want to solve the following problem in Mathematica:

Assume that $\lambda_2=-\frac{1}{2}+ r+\frac{1}{1+r}- r^2\log\frac{1+r}{r}$, $v\in[0,1]$ and $\theta\in[0,1]$. For pre-specified values of $k,r>0$, solve for $\{s,\lambda_1\}$ through the following two equations
$$\int_{\left\{\stackrel{2\theta v s+\lambda_2(1-\theta)r\geq\lambda_1}{\theta(v+r)\geq r}\right\}}(1-\theta)r\,dvd\theta+
\int_{\left\{\stackrel{2\theta v s+\lambda_2v\geq\lambda_1}{\theta(v+r)\geq r}\right\}}v\theta\,dvd\theta=s$$
$$\int_{\left\{\stackrel{2\theta v s+\lambda_2(1-\theta)r\geq\lambda_1}{\theta(v+r)\geq r}\right\}}\,dvd\theta+
\int_{\left\{\stackrel{2\theta v s+\lambda_2v\geq\lambda_1}{\theta(v+r)\geq r}\right\}}\,dvd\theta=k$$

For the first step, I tried to calculate the integrals using `Integrate` and `ImplicitRegion`, but got stuck here because Mathematica refuse to evaluate the expressions. Here are my codes:

```
λ2 = -(1/2) + r + 1/(1 + r) - r^2 Log[1 + 1/r];
k = 0.5;
r = 0.5;
R1 = ImplicitRegion[θ (v + r) > r && 2 θ v s + (1 - θ) r > λ1, {{θ, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}}];
R2 = ImplicitRegion[θ (v + r) < r && 2 θ v s + λ2 v > λ1, {{θ, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}}];
Integrate[(1 - θ) r, {θ, v} ∈ R1] + Integrate[θ v, {θ, v} ∈ R2]
Integrate[1, {θ, v} ∈ R1] + Integrate[1, {θ, v} ∈ R2]
```

Ultimately, I would like to plug back the solved $\{s,\lambda_1\}$, and plot the regions of `R1` and `R2`. But how can I fix the codes to solve the equations?

Comment: Mathematica may not be able to solve this problem.  However, to improve its chances of doing so, can you provide any bounds on `s` and  `λ1`?

Comment: Also, supposing that `Integrate` can be performed, how are `s` and `λ1` to be determined from the result?

Comment: GIven the specified values of k and r, the only unknowns would be s and lambda1, and we have two equations. So, hopefully, that would do the trick. I do anticipate that s is between 0 and 1, and lambda1 is positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This interesting problem can be solved numerically by computing `InterpolationFunction`s for the two sums of integrals in the last two lines of code in the Question.

```
λ2 = -(1/2) + r + 1/(1 + r) - r^2 Log[1 + 1/r];
k = 0.5;
r = 0.5;

t = Flatten[Table[
  R1 = ImplicitRegion[θ (v + r) > r && 2 θ v s + (1 - θ) r > λ1, {{θ, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}}];
  R2 = ImplicitRegion[θ (v + r) < r && 2 θ v s + λ2 v > λ1, {{θ, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}}]; 
  {{s, λ1}, 
      Integrate[(1 - θ) r, {θ, v} ∈ R1] + Integrate[θ v, {θ, v} ∈ R2],
      Integrate[1, {θ, v} ∈ R1] + Integrate[1, {θ, v} ∈ R2]}, 
  {s, 0, 1, .05}, {λ1, 0, 1, .05}], 1];
```

(I assume here that `s` and `λ1` both lie between zero and one.  If not, the limits on `Table` must be adjusted accordingly.)

```
f1 = Interpolation[Delete[3] /@ t];
Plot3D[f1[s, λ1], {s, 0, 1}, {λ1, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {s, λ1}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

```
f2 = Interpolation[Delete[2] /@ t];
Plot3D[f2[s, λ1], {s, 0, 1}, {λ1, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {s, λ1}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

In the absence of equations to determine `s` and `λ1` in terms of `f1` and `f2`, use `{f1[s, λ1] == .03, f2[s, λ1] == .135}` for illustrative purposes.  Then, the resulting values of `s` and `λ1` are

```
sol = FindRoot[{f1[s, λ1] == .03, f2[s, λ1] == .135}, {{s, .25}, {λ1, .35}}]
(* {s -> 0.153035, λ1 -> 0.362465} *)
```

Note that `FindRoot` requires fairly good initial guesses here to avoid attempting to search outside the domains of `f1` and `f2`.  Plots of the corresponding regions are

```
RegionPlot[(θ (v + r) > r && 2 θ v s + (1 - θ) r > λ1) /. sol, {θ, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, PlotPoints -> 60]
```

[image]

```
RegionPlot[(θ (v + r) < r && 2 θ v s + λ2 v > λ1) /. sol, {θ, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, PlotPoints -> 60]
```

[image]

Comment: Very tricky answer! Where did you find  `Delete[3] /@ t` to remove the third element, never seen it. Thanks.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  I had planned to use `Delete[#, 2]& /@ t` to remove the second column, then noticed the operator form of `Delete` in the documentation and decided to use it instead.  I used `Delete[3]` instead of `Most` so that the code for `f1` and `f2` would look similar.  Several list manipulation functions, for instance `Cases`, also have operator forms.  Best wishes.

Comment: Thanks it' s very helpful!

Comment: Thank you, this is super helpful! I have a syntax question, why do you need to `Flatten` the table?

Comment: @user391830  Table with two indices produces a nested `List`.  `Interpolation` expects a flat `List`.  See the third example under Scope in the `Interpolation` documentation.  Thanks for accepting my answer.  By the way, a symbolic solution may be possible by using a double `Integrate`, instead of using `ImplicitRegion`.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I now realize that the question can be solved analytically, for the most part, although not with `ImplicitRegion`.  The constraints embodied in `R1` and `R2` can be solved to obtain `θ` in terms of `v` and parameters.

```
r1c1 = Reduce[θ (v + r) > r && v > 0, θ] // Last
(* θ > 1/(1 + 2 v) *)
r1c2 = Reduce[2 θ v s + (1 - θ) r > λ1 && v > 0 && s > 0 && s != 1/(4 v), θ] // Last
(* (0 < s < 1/(4 v) && θ < (-1 + 2 λ1)/(-1 + 4 s v)) || 
   (s > 1/(4 v) && θ > (-1 + 2 λ1)/(-1 + 4 s v)) *)

r2c1 = Reduce[θ (v + r) < r && v > 0, θ] // Last
(* θ < 1/(1 + 2 v) *)
r2c2 = Reduce[2 θ v s + λ2 v > λ1 && v > 0 && s > 0, θ] // Last // Simplify
(* θ > (-0.196007 v + 0.5 λ1)/(s v) *)
```

The corresponding integrals then can be evaluated symbolically in just a few minutes, although the results are a bit long to reproduce here.  (Edit: Apply `N`, if necessary, so that r2c2 has the form shown.  Otherwise computations of `f1i2` and `f2i2` are very slow.)

```
f1i1 = Integrate[(1 - θ) r Boole[r1c1 && r1c2], {v, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 1}, 
    Assumptions -> λ1 > 0, GenerateConditions -> True];
f1i2 = Integrate[θ v Boole[r2c1 && r2c2], {v, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 1}, 
    Assumptions -> λ1 > 0 && s > 0, GenerateConditions -> True] // Simplify;
f2i1 = Integrate[Boole[r1c1 && r1c2], {v, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 1}, 
    Assumptions -> λ1 > 0, GenerateConditions -> True];
f2i2 = Integrate[Boole[r2c1 && r2c2], {v, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 1}, 
    Assumptions -> λ1 > 0 && s > 0, GenerateConditions -> True] // Simplify;
```

Determining `s` and `λ1` for the illustrative conditions used in my earlier numerical solution yields

```
sols = FindRoot[{f1i1 + f1i2 == .03, f2i1 + f2i2 == .135}, {{s, .25}, {λ1, .35}}]
(* {s -> 0.144367, λ1 -> 0.356326} *)
```

differing from the results of the earlier entirely numerical calculations by about 1%.

**Addendum: Simplified Code**

A simpler code producing essentially the same results is, in its entirety,

```
r = 1/2;
λ2 = N[-(1/2) + r + 1/(1 + r) - r^2 Log[1 + 1/r]];

f1i1 = Integrate[(1 - θ) r Boole[θ (v + r) > r && 2 θ v s + (1 - θ) r > λ1], 
    {v, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> λ1 > 0 && s > 0, GenerateConditions -> True];
f1i2 = Integrate[θ v Boole[θ (v + r) < r && 2 θ v s + λ2 v > λ1], 
    {v, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> λ1 > 0 && s > 0, GenerateConditions -> True]
    // Simplify;
f2i1 = Integrate[Boole[(1 - θ) r Boole[θ (v + r) > r && 2 θ v s + (1 - θ) r > λ1], 
    {v, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> λ1 > 0 && s > 0, GenerateConditions -> True];
f2i2 = Integrate[Boole[θ (v + r) < r && 2 θ v s + λ2 v > λ1], 
    {v, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> λ1 > 0 && s > 0, GenerateConditions -> True]
    // Simplify;
```

after which `s` and `λ1` can be determined as desired.